# Unable to Successfully Post Data to Website Using Python Requests - Recaptcha Issue

Tags: python, automation, python-requests

Python Request Posting Error

Hey!
I am making a python script. which will use the requests to post the data to the website and give a success response
But the problem is that. This is the [website](https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-checkbox.php)

but I am not able to post that.everytime i get the same initial response which i not need